# is possible data management with geoserver rest api

Tags: geoserver, rest, geoserver-rest-api

We can create data stores, workspaces with goserver rest api. Is possible to load data to a datastore via geoserver rest api?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly add data to an existing datastore, or remove the data and add replacement data.

This is documented in the [DataStore REST part of the GeoServer user manual](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/datastores.html#workspaces-ws-datastores-ds-file-url-external-extension). You'd just use a normal PUT operation. The key aspect is the "update" parameter, which selects whether the intention is append or overwrite. Of course, an append has to make sense for the type of DataStore you're changing.